# How do I add a parameter to category K2 back-end?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I need to add a parameter to category in K2 back-end in order to use it in a view. 
I've tried to add one: 
 
to 
components\com_k2\views\itemlist\tmpl\category.xml 
and 
administrator\components\com_k2\models\category.xml

but I still can't see the parameter in a category in K2 back-end.

How can I add a parameter?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Show some code, please. At a minimum, show the entries in each XML file. Wouldn't hurt to show your parameter call as well.

Answer (score 2):

k2 has the option to add extra fields.

Create an extra fields group and then add some fields to it and assign it to some categories.